# How to change HTML content with javascript after the POST method

Tags: javascript, html, events, post, onsubmit

I have troubles to change content in my HTML document with javascript after submitting a form with a POST method. I need to change the color of a div inside my HTML document to yellow, I have already done it, but the problem is that after it changes to yellow then the HTML website gets refreshed in the navigator and then it goes back to normal(white). It kind of flashes the yellow and then goes to white again.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form action="" method="post" onSubmit="return changeColor()">
.
.
.
<div id="divColor">
.
.
```

And this is my javascript code to change the div color:

```
function changeColor()
{
    var div = document.getElementById("courselist");
    div.style.backgroundColor='yellow';
}
```

I need to do it this way because is part of the assignment, so I cannot change the color with CSS and so far we can only use HTML and javascript. This is not the whole assignment in case somebody thinks I want to cheat, this is the part that I am stucked with. I cannot make the div keep the yellow color after the navigator has refreshed the HTML website after the POST method.

Thank you!

Comment: Use a cookie to save the colour of the div and set it when the page loads

Comment: Normally there would be some server-side code that knows whether it is the initial page request or the submit (without some kind of server-side processing a form submit is kind of pointless). Assuming you have to do it all client-side Musa's suggestion would work, or a method that might be a bit easier for a beginner is to add something to the query string.

Comment: @Carlos Vargas, Why you need to change color of `div#courselist` before posting form (and, as result, reloading page)? I cannot understand. Anyway, you can do one from: 1) do not submit form with `onsubmit` event (simply return `false` from `changeColor()`); 2) change color of `div#courselist` on server side: add `<input type='hidden' id='courselistcolor' name='courselistcolor' value=''>` into html form, inside `changeColor()` change value of this hidden input to _yellow_; on server side in PHP read value of `courselistcolor` parameter and set as initial color for `div#courselist`.

Answer (score 1):

When you submit a form, it goes to the next pages specified in `action=""`. Therefore, when you click the submit button, it changes color, then the next page loads. Due to the lack of page specified in `action=""`, it is reloading the same page so it turns yellow, then refreshes.

This is what you are probably looking for. You use AJAX to submit information to POST without actually loading a different page.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to achieve your aim.

1. Using ajax to submit information, so that the page is not refreshed， and the status remain.Or you can do it like the following, it has the same effect as ajax:

   < iframe name="myIfr" style="display:none">< /iframe>
   < form method="post" target="myIfr">...< /form>
2. Changing "action" of "", record the status in the url, like this: "mypage.php?status=1", After the page is refreshed, you can get the status from the url.
3. Using Cookie. I think it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could separate it so that the form only prints out if other conditions are met. Use a variable called $output_form (or whatever you feel like naming it) and set it to false, then have the code print out one thing before the POST is sent, and something after the POST is sent. Here is a really stripped down version of some code I finished a little while ago, might help you see what you can do:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

{SOME CODE HERE}

        $output_form = true;
    }

}
else{
    $output_form = true;
}

if (!$output_form){
    {SOME CODE HERE}
}
else{
    {OTHER STUFF HERE}
    $output_form = true;

    mysqli_close($dbc);
}
}

if ($output_form){
?>


<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

Comment: Assuming the OP is using PHP even though it's not mentioned anywhere in the question...

Comment: Still, the general principle of doing it with _some_ server-side language is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I finally solved my problem.
I had to return false in my changeColor() function and the website will change color, but not refresh itself. I like the approach with cookies.

Thank you for your help, I could not use either AJAX or PHP because they have not taught us that yet.